# How do i wrap each element in a tag with attribute?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to wrap each element in an anchor tag, but I'm unsure of how to do it.

I tried to use .each to run a function, that uses .wrap to wrap the element.

Here's what i did:

```
<div class="product-icon-container">
    <div class="product-icon product-share"><i class="fas fa-link"></i>Share</div>
    <div class="product-icon product-heart"><i class="far fa-heart"></i>Save</div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" class="post-url" value="<?php the_permalink() ?>">`

var postUrl = $(".post-url").val()

$(".post-url").each(function(){
    $(".product-share").wrap('a href="' + postUrl + '"></a>');
});
```

What happened was it wrapped all the elements as many times as the each function runs.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you call `.wrap()` for each .post-url (for example 10 times), without specifying which elements you want to use (class returns a collection, not single element).

Not so strong in jQuery, but it should be st. like this:

```
$(".post-url").each(function(){
    $(this).prev('.product-icon-container').find('.product-share').wrap('<a href="' + $(this).val() + '"></a>');
                                                                         ^^
});
```

In your `postUrl` it's always the same value, you don't change it for each `.post-url` element.

https://jsfiddle.net/rgdp9zLe/

Comment: That does not seem to work. And yes, postUrl's value is different. It contains the_permalink for the post, and it's different for each post..

Comment: @randomjsnoob: there was a typo, missing `<` at the beginning of wrapping `a`. Updated, I've added JSFiddle link.